# Serving executable file on App Engine changes file permissions

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyinstaller

I generated a Unix executable with PyInstaller. I then changed the permissions of the file using chmod +x+x+x my_file

`-rwxr-xr-x my_file`

When I serve that file from mysite.appspot.com/static/filename, I successfully download my app but the file permissions change and it can't be run as an executable anymore.

`-rw-r--r my_file_after_being_downloaded`

How can I serve my file while keeping its permissions unchanged?

(note that I can confirm that manually chmod-ing this downloaded file does turn it back into a Unix executable, and hence opens with double-click.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP doesn't support file permissions, i.e. there is no way to make downloaded file exacutable by default.

If your concern is to avoid users to mess with chmod, you can serve .tar.gz archive, which is able to keep records if file is executable or not

Comment: Tested this-- works perfectly. Thank you for teaching me something new @Marat.

Comment: note: I ended up using .zip compression as personal preference